# form opening on load

Tags: vb.net, refresh, ultrawingrid, form-load

My program was opening a different form to what I wanted it to. The answers solved it.

Basically I wanted to stop a form opening when the program started, but when it opened manually (on a button press), it updated the data. The second part of the problem has not been solved, but the first part has been.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    Public Class HomeForm
        Private WithEvents m_DataChangeForm As DataChangeForm

        Private Sub HomeForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            m_DataChangeForm = New DataChangeForm()
            m_DataChangeForm.Show()
        End Sub

        Private Sub OnDataSourceChanged(sender As Object, args As EventArgs) Handles m_DataChangeForm.OnDataSourceChanged
            MessageBox.Show("Data source changed!")
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class DataChangeForm
        Inherits Form

        Public Event OnDataSourceChanged(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)

        Private WithEvents m_Button As Button

        Public Sub New()
            m_Button = New Button()
            m_Button.Text = "Change"
            m_Button.Parent = Me
        End Sub

        Public Sub buttonClick(sender As Object, args As EventArgs) Handles m_Button.Click
            RaiseEvent OnDataSourceChanged(sender, args)
            Me.Close()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Reason your form is displayed before HomeForm is becaouse you call ShowDialog, it blocks until DataChangeForm is closed.

Comment: Hi, sorry I think you misunderstood what I meant. I don't want my `dataChangefrm` to be displayed at all on `Homefrm_Load, I just want the UltraGrid on `Homefrm` to update when the `dataChangefrm` is closed

Comment: I've added Show in form load event, but you can place it where you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your code from "Load" to "Shown" Event.

```
Private Sub Homefrm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

    Using fp = New dataChangefrm(m_database)

        If fp.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
           uwgHome.DataSource = Nothing
           loadData()

       End If
    End Using

    Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
loadData()
End Sub
```

Please have a look on the Handle in the first line. It depends on your Project.